# How to get properties of object from this HTTP response

Tags: html, angular, typescript, for-loop

I am trying to display the currency name or key like "USD", "AUD", "EUR" with their respective "last" and "buy" properties from this HTTP response:

[image]

and I just get back a list of "key" strings like this
[image]
but I can't figure out why my "key" is being returned as a string here.
It's making it difficult for me to programmatically access the properties for each currency

this is my **dashboard.component.ts**

```
  prices;
  bitcoinOwned;

  ngOnInit(): void {

  this.data.getPrice()
 .pipe(map(result => {this.prices = result, console.log("result", result) 
  for (let key in result) {console.log( key)}
} ))
  .subscribe();
     
}
```

my **data.service**

```
 getPrice() {
    var url = "https://blockchain.info/ticker";
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
```

and my **template**

```
<div>
    {{ prices |json }} 
</div> 

<div>
  USD last: {{ prices?.USD.last |json }} USD sell: {{ prices?.USD.sell |json }}
</div>
```

I can access the properties when I do it manually for each key like this but I need to iterate over the keys and do it more programmatically so any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use [Angular's KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe).

Then, you can do something like this:

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of prices | keyvalue">
       {{item.key}} last: {{ item.value.last |json }} {{item.key}} sell: {{ item.value.sell |json }}
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I've got another question.. if I say, I want to save the value of the "last" property for the EUR key in my dashboard component? and reference it later in my template, how can I do that? I tried it with Object.entries but that didn't work..

Comment: do you mean `saved=prices['EUR'].last` in .ts and then `{{saved}}` in html?

Comment: your `prices` holds a key/value pair - so to access any specific value, you must use the key. I suggest you play around with printing things like `prices` and `prices.keys` and `prices.values` etc and see what you can understand about it that way

Comment: okay, I will do that :) and I'm trying something like this: console.log("euro prices = ", Object.keys(this.prices.value('EUR'))) but I'm getting a "value is not a function error" so how could I select only the values where key = EUR in my .ts file?

Comment: `this.prices['EUR']`.
EUR is the key, so use it like you would with keyValue

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **Object.keys()** on the object to return the *key* value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys